# how to strip file out of an array which contains specific word, in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have some .txt files in the folder `messages`.
Each files has 6 lines. I file looks like this:

```
id_20197456 // identity
Friends //category
Test // title
10 Feb 2020 22:28 // date
John // writer
Lorum ipsum.... // message
```

The name of category is always on the **2nd** line

I have 5 files totally: **4** with category `Friends` and **1** with category `Offside`.
Now i want to strip out the file which has category `Offside`

This is what i have so far, to catch the file with category `Offside`:

```
$filterthis = strtolower('Offside');
$newslist = array();

$files = glob("messages/*.txt"); // Specify the file directory by extension (.txt)

foreach($files as $file) { // Loop through the files in the directory   

    $handle = @fopen($file, "r");

    if ($handle) {

        $lines = file($file); //file into an array

        $buffer = $lines[1]; // grab category line

        if(strpos(strtolower($buffer), $filterthis) !== FALSE) { // strtolower; search word not case sensitive  

                $newslist[] = $file; // The filename of the match
                // below the file which has Offside category
                print_r($newslist); // outputs: Array ( [0] => messages/id_20200210222825.txt )                 
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

For outputting all the files, i use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($newslist as $file) {
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // filedata into an array

    $file_id = $lines[0]; // file id
    $news_category = $lines[1]; //  news category
    $news_title = $lines[2]; //  news title
    $news_date = $lines[3]; // news date
    $news_author = $lines[4]; //  author name
    $news_message = $lines[5]; // news message

    fclose($fh);

    // all the echos's come here...
}
```

My question: How can i filter the files which do NOT have `Offside` as category in the foreach?
So the foreach should output all the files EXCEPT the ones who have `Offside` as category?

Comment: wouldnt a simple string comparison do the job?

Comment: I guess all you need is to change the comparison. Use `if(strpos(strtolower($buffer), $filterthis) === false) {` and then add all files that doesn't have the category you choose. Or use a different array if you need both info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) will do the job

Grab all files in the `messages` folder:

```
// read all files in messages folder
$dir = 'messages/';
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($file = readdir($dh))!== false){
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { // This line strips out . & ..
            $newslist[] = $dir.$file;                       
        }       
    }
}
closedir($dh);
```

Now filter the files in which category **Offside** ( you already did that)

```
// Strip file(s) with category Offside  
$strip_cat = strtolower('Offside');
$offside_array = array();

$files = glob("messages/*.txt"); // Specify the file directory by extension (.txt)

foreach($files as $file) { // Loop through the files in the directory   

    $handle = @fopen($file, "r");

    if ($handle) {

        $lines = file($file); //file into an array

        $buffer = $lines[1]; // grab category line

        if(strpos(strtolower($buffer), $strip_cat) !== FALSE) { // strtolower; search word not case sensitive   

                $offside_array[] = $file; // The filename of the match(es)

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Now compare the 2 arrays:

```
// compare the arrays and strip out the files which contain cat Offside
$filtered_newslist = array_diff($newslist, $offside_array);
```

**$filtered_newslist** is your new array which contains all the files except the ones who have category `Offside`

Your foreach loop:

```
foreach($filtered_newslist as $file) {
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // filedata into an array

    $file_id = $lines[0]; // file id
    // and so on...
}
```